# Fast computation of the area of a surface using MATLAB

Tags: integration, numerical-methods, matlab

I've written an algorithm in MATLAB which has to be real time (by real time I mean anything less than 1 s is perfect for my purpose and less than 10 s is still acceptably good). My algorithm contains a for loop which at each iteration it has to compute a certain number of areas. Each of these areas are computed using the following formula:
\begin{equation}  
A = \int_0^1\int_0^1 \sqrt{\det (g)}\ d u\ d v
\end{equation}
where $g$ is a $2\times 2$ matrix with polynomial entries (either linear or quadratic in variables $u$ and $v$). I already have managed to do that in Matlab in two ways as I explain below but both are very slow plus the fact that one of them has one additional problem in some special cases.
In the first attempt I wrote the following:

```
syms u v real
volume = sqrt(det(g));
area(i) = int(int(volume, u,0,1),v,0,1); # area of the i-th ruled surface
```

in this case the area is computed but its extremely slow. 
The other way that I thought solving it was to do the following:

```
syms u v real
volume = sqrt(det(g));
h = matlabFunction(volume);
area(i) = integral2(h,0,1,0,1);
```

This method makes it a bit faster (but noway close to being fast enough). It also has one additional problem, in some rare cases when computing the determinant of $g$, the polynomial obtained is univariate (depends on either $u$ or $v$) and when I use the `matlabFunction` command it only assigns one variable to it (`@(u)` or `@(v)`) which makes problems in the next line (as `integral2` doesn't recognize the other variable which is undefined by the `matlabFunction`). So my Questions are:

1. Is there a faster numerical-way to compute these integrals (or does Matlab have some special functions for a similar purpose)? regarding the accuracy, it is ok if its accurate up to 3 or 4 digits.
2. How can I force `matlabFunction` command to introduce the other variable in the case where `det(induced_metric)` is a univariate polynomial.

Thank you in advance,

Here I add the extra information regarding the ruled surfaces that I want to compute the area of.
Each of these are 2-dimensional surfaces originally in $\mathbb{R}^6$ associated with a metric $g^\prime$. Lets say each one of them is an enclosed area by the points $A$, $B$, $P$ and $Q$. Then I have the following parametrization for each of them:
\begin{equation}
X:\ (u,v) \longrightarrow
\left( \begin {array}{c}  \left(  \left( a_{{1}}-b_{{1}}-p_{{1}}+q_{{
1}} \right) v+p_{{1}}-a_{{1}} \right) u+ \left( -a_{{1}}+b_{{1}}
 \right) v+a_{{1}}\\  \left(  \left( a_{{2}}-b_{{2}}
-p_{{2}}+q_{{2}} \right) v+p_{{2}}-a_{{2}} \right) u+ \left( -a_{{2}}+
b_{{2}} \right) v+a_{{2}}\\  \left(  \left( a_{{3}}-
b_{{3}}-p_{{3}}+q_{{3}} \right) v+p_{{3}}-a_{{3}} \right) u+ \left( -a
_{{3}}+b_{{3}} \right) v+a_{{3}}\\  \left(  \left( a
_{{4}}-b_{{4}}-p_{{4}}+q_{{4}} \right) v+p_{{4}}-a_{{4}} \right) u+
 \left( -a_{{4}}+b_{{4}} \right) v+a_{{4}}\\ 
 \left(  \left( a_{{5}}-b_{{5}}-p_{{5}}+q_{{5}} \right) v+p_{{5}}-a_{{
5}} \right) u+ \left( -a_{{5}}+b_{{5}} \right) v+a_{{5}}
\\  \left(  \left( a_{{6}}-b_{{6}}-p_{{6}}+q_{{6}}
 \right) v+p_{{6}}-a_{{6}} \right) u+ \left( -a_{{6}}+b_{{6}} \right) 
v+a_{{6}}\end {array} \right) 
\end{equation} 
Then in order to compute the area of the surface I have to obtain the induced metric on it, which earlier I named it $g$, I obtained it by computing $\frac{\partial X}{\partial u}$ and $\frac{\partial X}{\partial v}$, and then 
\begin{eqnarray}
g_{1,1} = \langle\frac{\partial X}{\partial u}, \frac{\partial X}{\partial u} \rangle ,\\
g_{1,2} = g_{2,1} = \langle\frac{\partial X}{\partial u}, \frac{\partial X}{\partial v} \rangle ,\\
g_{2,2} = \langle\frac{\partial X}{\partial v}, \frac{\partial X}{\partial v} \rangle .
\end{eqnarray}
where $\langle - , - \rangle$ is the scalar product computed with respect to the metric $g^\prime$ (which is symmetric and positive-definite).

Comment: Did you try to explicitly provide the metric matrix without using any symbolic variables? It might be that there is still some substantial overhead even after using `matlabFunction`.

Comment: @LutzL Unfortunately it is not possible to define it without syms, since each entry of the `induced_metric` matrix is of degree 2 depending on `u` and `v`. If it was of one variable it was then possible to define the polynomial with just a matrix in matlab. But I have no idea how to do it for polynomials with 2 or more variables.

Comment: I do not understand your restriction. `function z=f(x,y) z=x.^3+x.*y.^2+y.^5; end` is a polynomial in two variables. The conversion of symbolic derivatives requires more effort, if such are contained in the metric computation.

Comment: @LutzL I didn't get what you mean well. Are you suggesting writing `volume` as function of `u` and `v` by defining a range for these variables (like `u = 0:0.01:10`)? If thats so it is not possible for me as I do not have the formula for the `volume`. I actually have `d_u` and `d_v` (which are two vectors) and then I have the `metric_tensor` of $\mathbb{R}^6$, then I obtain the `induced_metric` by computing each entry, Like `induced_metric(1,2) = d_x_u' * metric_tensor * d_x_v;`. The formula for the `volume` would be too long to be implemented directly in front of the integral.

Comment: "either linear or quadric": don't you mean quadratic ?

Comment: This just highlights that the information you give is not sufficient to make any suggestions for possible improvements. Are `d_u` and `d_x_u` the same, most likely the `u` derivative of the `x` vector? Do you compute `d_u` resp. `d_x_u` from `x` by symbolic differentiation? How complicated would it be to apply algorithmic differentiation, eliminating all symbolic variables?

Comment: @YvesDaoust yes I mean of total degree 2 with respect to the variables u and v. It was a typo but unfortunately I can't edit one word.

Comment: You say "ruled surface". If this is true, maybe this property can be exploited.

Comment: Do the areas change from one iteration to the next ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust ok, I edit the post in few minutes and I add the symbolic information regarding the structure of these ruled surfaces and the way I obtain $g$.

Comment: No, I am asking if the integrals you have to compute differ at each iteration. $(u,v)$ always cover the unit square it seems.

Comment: Ruled or not ruled ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust , yes at each iteration it computes a different ruled surface. Roughly speaking, you can imagine it as a leaflet consisting of n pages (each ruled surface that I want to compute is a page of this leaflet (brochure)). I hope that this illustrates the shape of the whole object for you (as English is not my mother tongue my explanation might be a bit vague ).

Comment: @YvesDaoust In fact these surfaces differ in the coordinates $A$, $B$, $P$ and $Q$.

Comment: So your integrand for the bi-linear patch has the form $\sqrt{(a_2u^2+a_1u+a_0)(b_2v^2+b_1v+b_0)-(c_3uv+c_2u+c_1v+c_0)^2}$ and all you need for a faster computation is to compute these coefficients from the vectors $A,B,P,Q$.

Comment: @LutzL yes, do you suggest computing all such coefficients for all surfaces at once using vectorial computation in MATLAB and then define your function by @(u,v)  and use integral2 ?

Comment: I do not know what level of vectorization will prove best. Usually more vectorization is faster, at least where linear operations are concerned. It might be that calling the integration on a vector of non-linear function orients its effort (adaptive sub-divisions) on the worst patch, doing too much work on easy patches relative to calling each integration separately. However, computing scalar products and norm squares can very well done simultaneously, as that is a homogeneous effort over all patches.

Comment: So you have a bilinear hypersurface in $\mathbb R^6$, which is indeed ruled, but the metric expression doesn't define a ruled surface in $\mathbb R^2$.

Comment: @YvesDaoust yes it is a ruled surface in $\mathbb{R}^6$ but it is not a hypersurface as it is of dimension 2 and the ambient space is 6 dimensional!

Comment: @ArvinRasoulzadeh: how do you call such a variety, then ?

Comment: The gradient vector can be expressed as $$\nabla((S_{00}(1-u)+S_{10}u)(1-v)+(S_{01}(1-u)+S_{11}u)v)=(\Delta_{.0}(1-v)+\Delta_{.1}v,\Delta_{0.}(1-u)+\Delta_{1.}u),$$

so that the $g_{ij}$ functions are bilinear or univariate quadratic in $u,v$. It would be interesting to check if there is cancellation of the higher degree terms in $g$ so that the resulting polynomial is cubic rather than quartic.

Comment: @YvesDaoust well I hadn't referred to it as a variety before (I was treating it as a smooth manifold)... but maybe one can write it as the intersection of 4 real algebraic hypersurfaces (but I'm not sure).

Comment: How about using the quadrature and replace exact integral by, say, the midpoint rule? Though I’d guess that symbolic computations take most of the time and thus integrating is not a problem. Btw, are symbolic computations parallelized in matlab?

Comment: And maybe I am being stupid but can’t you define the function to be integrated explicitly as a function of u,v, A,B,P,Q and just feed the values for the variables thus avoiding symbolic computations for each surface?

Comment: @VorKir I think that symbolic computations can not be parallel in MATLAB. Yes some approximations of that kind may be possible too. Now I'm thinking about triangulating it and then compute the sum of the areas of the triangles. If it was computationally ok, then perhaps I post its MATLAB code here.

Comment: It's just that I think all the described computations should be fast, except for the way how integration is done (which can be replaced by quadratures) and symbolic computations